# Drupal sites/default/settings.php issue on pantheon

Tags: 7

I am a complete noob at this site business, and I'm facing what seems to be a very simple problem with my drupal site (hosted on pantheon):
[image]

I don't know where this file located nor how to copy it to the other .php files (whose location I also don't know). I would really appreciate *detailed* help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Drupal. If you need detailed information about where to locate it on *Pantheon*, I suggest you try Pantheon user support.

Answer (score 1):

On Pantheon you can simply go to your codebase where the root of Drupal installation is placed you will find directories like `includes, misc, modules, themes` and `sites` from here you need to go into `sites/default/` you will a file named `default.settings.php` you need to copy this file and place at the same location with name `settings.php`.

This is the main configuration file of your website and all config settings will go here.

Comment: Could you explain how to find this codebase on the pantheon site? I'm having trouble.

Comment: contact me on Skype- (ashu.bairagi)  there we can have detailed discussion